# How to return the "third nested" association in findAll of Sequelize.js

Tags: sequelize.js

I am having a hard time how to do that, I googled a lot but couldn't find.

I have a product that have a subcategory and the subcategory has a category.

```
product                subcategory            category 
id_subcategory           id                     id
                         id_category


 findAll({include: Category}); //didn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

That was a hard one, after a million tries:

```
  let anunciosPesquisa = await anuncio.findAll({  include: [{ model: Subcategoria, include: { model: Categoria} }]  });
```